# When to get height angular-populated div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have some content inside a DIV populated using ng-bind, I would like to do some calculation based on the height of the DIV. I'm currently doing this using a directive. However, the directive's DOM selector always end up with the initial height of the DIV (without any content populated).

So, how/when can I get actual height of the DIV after population?

Here are the relevant code:

```
<div class="main-header" fit-screen>
  <img class="full-height" ng-src="{{ data.images.cover.image_url }}" alt="{{ data.description.name }}" />
</div>
<div class="product-basic-info-container">
  <!--all content populated using ng-bind-->
  <h1 class="product-name" ng-bind="data.description.name"></h1>
  <h2 class="product-desc" ng-bind="data.description.summary"></h2>
  <div class="product-price clearfix">
    <span class="price now-price" ng-bind="'¥' + data.prices.price"></span>
    <a ng-href="{{ data.buy_url }}" class="form-button buy-button">Buy</a>
  </div>
</div>


var fitScreenDir = function() {
  return {
    link : function() {
      /* Fit both header and basic info into one page */
      var viewport_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var header_elem = document.querySelector( '.main-header' );
      var product_info_elem = document.querySelector( '.product-basic-info-container' );
      var product_info_height, result_height, original_height, new_css;

      /* Get basic info height and substract from viewport height */
      product_info_height = product_info_elem.offsetHeight;
      result_height = ( viewport_height - product_info_height );

      /* Set new height */
      new_css = {
        'height'          : result_height + 'px'
      };
      angular.element( header_elem ).css( new_css );
    }
  };
};

app.directive( 'fitScreen', fitScreenDir );
```

Comment: Depends on how you populate it. `$watch` combined with a short `$timeout` maybe? Please show us relevant code. Right now there's close to no information in your question.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I have added my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to retrieve the height in the body of the `link` function of the directive. This will be before your div is populated with whatever your binding to.

You can set a up a watch on your scope and execute a function whenever the value changes (read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). The `bindedProperty` needs to be available on scope of your directive.

```
scope.$watch('bindedProperty', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue === oldValue) return;

  // el.height();
})
```